# How do I get the current unix timestamp from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

[Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the number of seconds since midnight UTC January 1, 1970.

How do I get the correct unix timestamp from PostgreSQL?

When comparing to [currenttimestamp.com](http://www.currenttimestamp.com/) and [timestamp.1e5b.de](http://timestamp.1e5b.de/) I don't get the expected time from PostgreSQL:

This returns the correct timestamp:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from now());
```

While this doesn't:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc');
```

I live in time zone UTC +02. What is the correct way to get the current unix timestamp from PostgreSQL?

This returns the correct time and time zone:

```
SELECT now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2011-05-18 10:34:10.820464+02
```

Another comparison:

```
select now(), 
extract(epoch from now()), 
extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc');
              now              |    date_part     |    date_part
-------------------------------+------------------+------------------
 2011-05-18 10:38:16.439332+02 | 1305707896.43933 | 1305700696.43933
(1 row)

Unix timestamp from the web sites:
1305707967
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

In postgres, `timestamp with time zone` can be abbreviated as `timestamptz`, and `timestamp without time zone` as `timestamp`. I will use the shorter type names for simplicity.

Getting the Unix timestamp from a postgres `timestamptz` like `now()` is simple, as you say, just:

```
select extract(epoch from now());
```

That's really all you need to know about getting the absolute time from anything of type `timestamptz`, including `now()`.

Things only get complicated when you have a `timestamp` field.

When you put `timestamptz` data like `now()` into that field, it will first be converted to a particular timezone (either explicitly with `at time zone` or by converting to the session timezone) and the timezone information *is discarded*. It no longer refers to an absolute time. This is why you don't usually want to store timestamps as `timestamp` and would normally use `timestamptz` — maybe a film gets released at 6pm on a particular date *in every timezone*, that's the kind of use case.

If you only ever work in a single time zone you might get away with (mis)using `timestamp`. Conversion back to `timestamptz` is clever enough to cope with DST, and the timestamps are assumed, for conversion purposes, to be in the current time zone. Here's an example for GMT/BST:

```
select '2011-03-27 00:59:00.0+00'::timestamptz::timestamp::timestamptz
     , '2011-03-27 01:00:00.0+00'::timestamptz::timestamp::timestamptz;

/*
|timestamptz           |timestamptz           |
|:---------------------|:---------------------|
|2011-03-27 00:59:00+00|2011-03-27 02:00:00+01|
*/
```

*<sub>[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7359c7eebc3167111b344c2bae0fa326)</sub>*

But, note the following confusing behaviour:

```
set timezone to 0;

values(1, '1970-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp::timestamptz)
    , (2, '1970-01-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp::timestamptz);

/*
|column1|column2               |
|------:|:---------------------|
|      1|1970-01-01 00:00:00+00|
|      2|1970-01-01 00:00:00+00|
*/
```

*<sub>[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=76b83a6a15cd3c46b43a6eebbc66e92a)</sub>*

This [is because](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN6247):

> PostgreSQL never examines the content of a literal string before determining its type, and therefore will treat both […] as timestamp without time zone. To ensure that a literal is treated as timestamp with time zone, give it the correct explicit type…In a literal that has been determined to be timestamp without time zone, PostgreSQL will silently ignore any time zone indication

Comment: Any idea how to convert the resulting decimal into an integer without decimal point (I mean merging the number and the decimal as one big integer). Thanks.

Comment: Like [this](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6618d6e22b6950dc19c6d3db9931538d) but I'm sure you don't really want to do that. Perhaps you want to multiply by a power of ten and strip any remaining decimals?

Comment: @W.M. Maybe like this? `SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(epoch FROM NOW())*1000);`

Answer (score 32):

```
SELECT extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc');
```

doesn't return the correct timestamp because postgres timezone conversion throws away timezone information from the result:

> 9.9.3. AT TIME ZONE
>
> Syntax: timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE zone
> Returns: timestamp with time zone
> Treat given time stamp without time zone as located in the specified time zone
>
> Syntax: timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE zone
> Returns: timestamp without time zone
> Convert given time stamp with time zone to the new time zone, with no time zone designation

afterwards, extract looks at timestamp without time zone and considers it to be a local time (although it is already utc in fact).

The correct way would be:

```
select now(),
       extract(epoch from now()),                                          -- correct
       extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc'),                       -- incorrect
       extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'utc');    -- correct

          now                  |    date_part     |    date_part     |    date_part
-------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
 2014-10-14 10:19:23.726908+02 | 1413274763.72691 | 1413267563.72691 | 1413274763.72691
(1 row)
```

In the last line the first `at time zone` performs the conversion, the second one assigns new time zone to the result.